# How to do some operation in the elements of a vector with previous elements

Tags: r

This may have been a very basic question, but I am scratching my head ..

Suppose I have a vector `v` with 10 elements

```
v <- 1:10
> v
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Now I want to perform some operation (2 argument function) say `+` on its elements with previous elements, to get an output like.. `1+1` `1+2` `2+3` `3+4`.. and so on.  For the first element where no previous value is there, I'll take first value only.  I can perform this operation by manually creating another vector something like `c(v[1], v[-length(v)])`, *but I think/presume there may be some direct method/in-built function to do so.*

```
> v + c(v[1], v[-length(v)])
 [1]  2  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19

#OR if product is the operation

> v * c(v[1], v[-length(v)])
 [1]  1  2  6 12 20 30 42 56 72 90
```

Please guide

Comment: You have a very simple solution to your problem, why do you presume there is a built-in function to do this? Is it a commonly used procedure in mathematics that has a name? On the surface this looks like a niche problem to me, so I don't see why there would be a function to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with `dplyr::lag` or `data.table::shift`, although I am not sure if this is what you were looking for.

```
v + dplyr::lag(v, default = v[1])
#[1]  2  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ronak.  I am aware of lead and lag functions of tidyverse.  Actually I am looking for some `accumulate` type of function where I can give a function as an argument but simultaneously also restrict the number of elements on which the function has to be applied.  like `somefunction(v, 1, .init = v[1])`.  maybe Kraigolas's comment sum it up that there may not be a baseR function for doing this.  Thanks for help anyways.

Comment: There is a base R function for that it is `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE`. Note that the example that you have shown is not the right one then for `purrr::accumulate` and `Reduce`. `accumulate` uses output of previous iteration as input to the next one. In your example, you are taking previous value and not the previous output. Your example does not depend on previous output.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may want to try `mapply`.

```
v <- 1:10

init <- v[1]

mapply(`+`, c(init, v[-length(v)]), v)
#  [1]  2  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19

mapply(`*`, c(init, v[-length(v)]), v)
#  [1]  1  2  6 12 20 30 42 56 72 90

mapply(`^`, c(init, v[-length(v)]), v)
# [1]  1  1  8  81  1024  15625  279936  5764801  134217728  3486784401
```